# Can keychain on iOS device save anything different than NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, keychain

I want to save an array/object into keychain but it looks like keychain only support `NSString`. Anyone has tried to do this before? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keychain can save anything that obeys NSCoding

See [this](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html) blog for a class which you can use as a starting point.